# Is there a name for the function $f(a,b)=\max(a-b,0)$?

Tags: terminology

Is there any conventional (standard) terminology for the function $f(a,b)=\max(a-b,0)$?

This function "caps" the value of $a-b$ with at least $0$.

Comment: Not really. There are no names for such special functions.

Comment: Some would call $x \mapsto \max(x,0)$ a **ramp**. It is also the primitive of the Heaviside step.

Comment: This is called the positive part of $(a-b)$. In general $h(x)=x^+:=\max\{x , 0\}$.

Comment: Oh, I can't remember exactly the name but we had $a \dot- b$ notation for this function in Discrete Mathematics course.

Comment: It can also be written as $f(a,b)=\frac12(a-b+|a-b|)$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: Thank you! This indeed seems to be the correct terminology, except for the `a-b` part, since the `ramp` function is defined to take a single input value. So I suppose `diffRamp` would be the most suitable answer to my question. Thanks!

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb I would say it's the *composition* of scalar field $(a,b) \mapsto a - b$ and function $x \mapsto \max(x,0)$.

Comment: If $a>b$, then $f(a,b)=a-b$. Otherwise, $f(a,b)=0$ (if $a \le b$).

Answer (score 0):

The standard name for this is **floored subtraction**.